# Why do I need to evaluate range-v3 views to be able to use them with concat?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I’m trying to concatenate multiple views on a move-only type:

```
using namespace ranges;
auto v = views::ints(0, 4) |
         views::transform([](int i) { return std::make_unique<int>(i); });
auto w = views::ints(4, 8) |
         views::transform([](int i) { return std::make_unique<int>(i); });
auto x = views::concat(v, w) | to<std::vector>();
```

However, this does not compile for me and I can’t make much sense of the error message (see https://godbolt.org/z/TcoP8djnz).

If I choose to evaluate `v` and `w` first, though, the code compiles:

```
auto v = views::ints(0, 4) |
         views::transform([](int i) { return std::make_unique<int>(i); }) |
         to<std::vector>();
auto w = views::ints(4, 8) |
         views::transform([](int i) { return std::make_unique<int>(i); }) |
         to<std::vector>();
auto x = views::concat(v | views::move, w | views::move) | to<std::vector>();
```

Why is that? According to the [range-v3 doxygen](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1concat__fn.html) the requirements are that the parameters to `concat` are `viewable_range`s and `input_range`s. While I’m not sure I fully understand the meaning of the former concept, I think that both of these requirements should be met even in the first case.

Btw, the first case also compiles when I replace `make_unique` with `make_shared`, i.e. I replace it with a copyable type.

Comment: Looks like a bug in range-v3. If you look at the error message, it comes from the `to<>()`, not the concat, because at some-point range-v3 tries to emplace a "variant" (not std::variant) from a `std::unique_ptr<> const&`, which of course fails. Even if you `| views::move` on the views (and/or after the `concat`), the error is the same.